# Should I say: She is 'no' student or She is 'not' a student?

Tags: word-choice, negation

I'm always confused with that issue. Should I say

> She is **no** student

or

> She is **not** a student

Or are *both of them* equal? If they are, what is the difference between them?

Comment: If you use "not", you need an article: "she is not ***a*** student".

Comment: I forgot to put the article 'a'. I edited it thanks to you.

Comment: You might also hear "She is no student of mine," indicating that she may be a student, but the speaker does not teach her.

Comment: Compare "[That's no moon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVekNsgUqn4)". They're both valid usage but "That's not a moon" would have been less emphatic.

Comment: Famously: *Senator, I served with Jack Kennedy. I knew Jack Kennedy. Jack Kennedy was a friend of mine.* [*Senator, you're no Jack Kennedy.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senator,_you're_no_Jack_Kennedy)

Comment: Using *"not a"* is far more common in daily usage, if you're trying to decide between the two.

Comment: @skeggse No! "She's no student of mine" indicates much more than that she might be a student but not the speaker's student. It's a very strong statement suggesting that the speaker is offended that you even thought she was their student. "She's not a student of mine" means that she's not the speaker's student but says nothing about whether she's somebody else's student. If you wanted to be really unambiguous, you should say, "I don't know if she's a student; she's not a student of mine."

Comment: The "She is no student", besides empathic, sounds more archaic. You will find it much more frequently in old texts, while "not a" will be more common in modern ones.

Comment: @SF "emphatic" (with force), not "empathic" (with empathy). :-)

Comment: @David Richerby yeah that makes sense. I was imagining a specific intonation when I wrote that comment, which makes it sound archaic without adding all that subtext. I'd say you could do something similar with "not a" as well.

Comment: They are not the same. "She is not a student" means she isn't enrolled.  "She is no student" means she is incapable or unwilling to be a suitable student.

Comment: Useful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/12027/the-use-of-no-good-and-not-good-in-this-context

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can say either one, but they have different effects.

"She is not a student" is a simple statement of fact. "She is no student" is usually an emphatic statement, which only really makes sense when you're denying somebody else's implication that she's a student. For example, if one professor says, "A student asked me a question about [some crackpot theory] after yesterday's lecture," another professor might say, "She's no student! She's just some woman who slips into lectures so she can ask her crazy questions."  You could also use it figuratively, to mean that she's such a bad student that she doesn't deserve the name: "Mary? Ha! She's no student. I mean, she pays her fees and comes to lectures but have you ever seen her actually study anything? I haven't!"

Comment: Irish here. I doubt it. I'd find that construction equally emphatic, and would be very surprised to hear it used for simple negation.

Comment: I'd perhaps emphasise your first sentence to state that while both are valid, they are **very** different usages. You kind of say this, but "They have different effects" is a little soft, IMO.

Comment: In a famous example of this, Dan Quayle, while running for VP, would routinely say that he had as much experience as Jack Kennedy did when he was running for president.  To which Lloyd Bentsen responded "Senator, I served with Jack Kennedy. I knew Jack Kennedy. Jack Kennedy was a friend of mine. Senator, you're no Jack Kennedy."

Comment: Four years later, 81-year-old Ronald Reagan made fun of this after Bill Clinton compared himself to Thomas Jefferson, saying "This fellow they've nominated claims he's the new Thomas Jefferson. Well, let me tell you something. I knew Thomas Jefferson. He was a friend of mine. And governor, you're no Thomas Jefferson."

Answer (score 18):

You *can* say "She is no student."

This "style" is usually used for emphasis.

> She is no student! She's an imposter, just a journalist trying to get her story!"

---

You *cannot* say "She is not student". Here you need an article. Your [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/revisions/71270/2) makes your example correct.

> She is not **a** student.

Comment: The question was updated to correct the "not a student" part.  Looks like that was a typo.  You may need to revise your answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

The first sentence can mean that she is not a student despite seeming like one. Or that she did a bad job at being a student. This is a bit of a strong statement.

The second sentence is not grammatical. It should be

> She is **not** *a* student.

The meaning of this sentence is self-explanatory.

To sum up, the two sentences **do not** mean identical things.

Comment: The first could also have a meaning of "While she is enrolled in the university, her behaviors are unbecoming of a student" or "With her behavior, I wouldn't expect her to be a student for long".  You're right that either way it's a strong (and particularly offensive) statement.

Answer (score 6):

The two statements have very different connotations. "She is not a student" simply means what it says: "she is not a student, she is employed as a cleaner". While "She is no student" probably means something like "She might be registered as a student, but she's making no effort to study"

Comment: I already said all of that in my answer, two hours before you.

Answer (score 2):

I am an educated native speaker of American English. In both British English and American English, I believe, "She is no student" is usually a flippant judgment, while "She is not a student" does not imply any moral judgment, unless the judgment is implied by tone of voice.

Answer (score 1):

"She is *not* a student" is just a statement, stating that she is not a student at all.
"She is *no* student" can mean different things, and is more *empathic*.

"She is *no* student" can mean that she does not study at all, she does not participate in projects, or even she does not even **go** to the school. It can generally mean "She **does not act** like a student" or "She **is not** a student".

Examples:

> She neither studies nor she does her homework. She is no student!

or

> She hasn't ever written an essay, so she is no student.

But you can't say:

> She hasn't ever written an essay, so she is not a student.

Answer (score -2):

The two different sentences **She is 'no' student** or **She is 'not' a student** are different in their meaning. **And can be used accordingly based on the context that you have.**

**1.She is 'no' student**

> This sentence means that someone is pretending like a student, who is actually not a student.

**2.She is 'not' a student**

> This sentence is more clear and precise to say without any doubt that the person who is referred here (He or She), is not a student.

**The following explanation will give you a short introductions to situations where these words are used.**

The proper and formal pronunciation is to spell like:

- *She is not a student*.

**Difference between no and not**

We can make a word, expression or clause negative by putting *not* before it.

- I do not intend to resign.
- Ask James, not his wife.
- Not surprisingly, they got divorced within a couple of months.
- You can come tomorrow, but not on Friday.

*No* is used in a different way. It is used with a noun or an –ing form to mean ‘not any’.

- No students joined the program. (= There weren’t any students who joined the program.)
- No man is perfect. (= There aren’t any perfect men.)
- She has got no children. (= She hasn’t got any children.)
- I have got no money to buy food. (= I haven’t got any money to buy food.)

In some cases the structures *verb + not* and *no + noun* can have similar meanings.

- There wasn’t any reply. = There was no reply.

**Exercise**

Complete the following sentences *not* or *no*.

1) We have ______ money.
2) It is ______ true.
3) He is ______ stupid.
4) She has got ______ friends.
5) She has ______ got any money.

Answers:

1) We have no money.
2) It is not true.
3) He is no stupid.
4) She has got no friends.
5) She has not got any money.

Comment: This doesn't relate to not/no being used after the `to be` verb and before a noun, which is what this question was about.

Comment: Praveen@ yes, it was. I ranked your answer up.

Comment: You can say "He is no idiot", but "He is no stupid" would not be standard; "stupid" _can_ be a noun in that way, but is rare.

Comment: Your opening statement makes it sound like "She is no student" is improper or informal, neither of which is true. The rest of your answer might be helpful to a learner, though.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for the edit, anyway within my limited knowledge I tried to help, which resulted in down voting and loss of reputation

Comment: @PraveenG - Don't take downvoting so personally. It happens. And you haven't really lost reputation. You got one upvote (which gives you 10 points) and three downvotes (which gives you -6), so, in the end, you stilll *gained* reputation for your efforts.

Comment: @all down voters : better you guys explain why you down voted my answer, you goons.

Answer (score -3):

After I cheeked this issue on so called a professional book of grammar (see below) I found these things:

"Negative statements are formed with the help of 'not' and 'no'

> **NOT** + verb, or + many / much / a lot of
>
> **NO**  + adjective, or + noun, or + negative short answer

"Guess the difference and give at least one contextual sentence: "She is not a student" 2. She is no student" end of quotation.

These things are from "English grammar for university students" (Harkiv 2010. p. 8)

Now, I don't understand the rull that "not" comes with verb etc. while in our case is not+ noun rather than not+ verb.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. You seem to be saying that you tried to find the answer in a textbook but didn't understand what it said. If so, you should ask about that in a new question.

Comment: I see what was the problem in my comment. I edited it and maybe now it will be better and clearer for you.