# The grammar lying under "I'm no Superman."

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

I'm living in a non-English-speaking country, so I usually contact English only through mass media (drama, for example). I've seen some use cases where *no* is used as if it's interchangeable to *not a*, like in the example "I'm no Superman" from the drama Scrubs, but I'm not sure if it's a standard (or formal) usage or not. Is there an underlying grammar behind this, or is it just a slang?

Comment: Your question should end 'is it just slang?'; we do not say 'a slang'.

Comment: Highly related: [Should I say: She is 'no' student or She is 'not' a student?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/71270/41273)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying grammar is that "no" can be used a determiner. As a determiner it means "not any" or sometimes "not allowed" or "not at all a".  So we can say, with "no" as a determiner:

> There is no water here  (not any)
>
> There is no smoking in the building (not allowed)
>
> He is no fool.  (Not at all a)

It is not slang, and can also be used in formal situations.