# No different from / not different from

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> Your suggestion is **no** different from that of the other employees.
>
> Your suggestion is **not** different from that of the other employees.

Which is the correct word to use here *no* or *not*  and what's the difficulty in their meaning ?

PS : while using **no** instead of *not* *than* sounds better to my ears than using *from*

I.e.

> > Your suggestion is no different than that of the other employees

Comment: Similar: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/12027/the-use-of-no-good-and-not-good-in-this-context

Comment: "..no different from.." isn't wrong, despite what the answers below say, and is in fact the more popular option. I'm not sure if this is idiomatic or not, though, so I'll leave it to somebody else to give you a better answer. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+different+from%2Cnot+different+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20different%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20different%20from%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

"no" can be used as an adverb. So it can modify an adjective.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/no_3

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is:
No different than usually has a negative connotation.
He is no different than he was 10 years ago. (He's supposed to be better, but he isn't.)

He is not different from he was 10 yrs ago. (He was a great man and he still is)

Answer (score 0):

Using *no different* is correct. Using *not different* is correct, but sounds awkward to me in this context - I would find it more natural to say *the same as*.

*Not different* has the sense of absoluteness, and using it indicates that the suggestion is either different or not different. *No different* has the sense of being on a scale including *no different, slightly different, very different* etc.

Answer (score -1):

*Your suggestion is not different from those of the other employees* is correct. Your sentence carries a negative implication by adding *not* to the main verb *is* followed by the adjective *different* like *She is not kind*

- Your first sentence*Your suggestion is no different from that of the other employees* is wrong because there's no **object** and you can't use the determiner **no** followed by an adjective, it takes a noun here. So you can paraphrase the first sentence as *There is no difference between your suggestion and those of the other employees*

Answer (score -2):

No and not are the two most common words we use to indicate negation.

but,

we use " no " before a " noun phrase " only

but we can use " not " with any other phrase or clause

in your sentence

" Your suggestion is no different from that of the other employees. "

is wrong , because " difference " is an adjective here not a noun

so,

" Your suggestion is not different from that of the other employees. "

is the correct answer.